# Director/Lingo, making an application toggle between fullscreen and windowed?

Tags: lingo, adobe-director

I recently had a client contact me asking for an update to his project that I used to maintain/develop years ago.

It was done using Macromedia Director (now Adobe Director) and Lingo. Since I haven't developed *anything* using these technology in such a long time I need some assistance.

The majority of the changes are simple, but what has got me stumped is making the application be able to toggle between full-screen projector and windowed-mode.

This is how it is organised:

- I have a stub projector, which is lightweight and ensures a quick start-time.
- The stub projector loads the main movie. `("@::Content:Main")`
- This stub projector is published with in full-screen mode.

Now, I can create a projector that is windowed and one that is full-screen mode by publishing separate executables. However what the client wants is the ability to switch this at runtime - is this *even* possible?

I have found a few workarounds that kinda work (setting the display-rect and stage-rect to the desktop size) but introduce numerous compatibility issues.

Any advice? Solutions?

I am tempted to say that it isn't possible to switch at runtime and recommend that he publishes either a full-screen or a windowed version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference: http://www.directorforum.com/showthread.php?p=38795#post38795

> Well there are different ways to
>   define "full screen", but all can be
>   done at runtime:
>
> 1) The projector automatically adjusts
>   the computer's display resolution to
>   match the dimensions of the movie and
>   hides the taskbar/dock. This is
>   generally what "full screen" means in
>   modern parlance. You can check out
>   various Xtras for switching the
>   resolution on the fly.
>
> 2) In Director terms, publishing a
>   projector 'full screen' just means
>   that the projector window has no
>   titlebar, takes up the full dimensions
>   of the display, hides the
>   taskbar/dock, and has the movie
>   content centered on screen framed by a
>   solid background color. This is a
>   pretty lame implementation of full
>   screen since it doesn't make the movie
>   appear any bigger onscreen. This can
>   be set at runtime by manipulating the
>   rects that you mention and using an
>   Xtra to hide the taskbar. Not sure
>   what "compatibility issues" you ran
>   into.
>
> 3) Graphically stretch the movie so
>   that its actual content takes up the
>   entire screen. The easiest way to do
>   this is by altering the drawRect. But
>   this can result in distorted graphics
>   depending on how much stretching is
>   occurring, since no antialiasing is
>   used to smooth the stretched pixels.